# Creating too many adapters for 24 Hour format to 12 Hour format Time change

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-listview, android-adapter

I have an application which displays present time at all Locations, However user can change time format from settings

#### User is Shown time in 24 Hour format

[image: 24 hour time]

#### User selects Settings

[image: Open settings]

#### User changes time format

[image: Change Time format]

#### Time is changed to new format

[image: New format]

### This is working correctly without any errors. Real issue is I strongly feel coding design being used is seriously flawed

### Coding Design:

1) I created a JSON file with all Time zone information(Some thing like shown here)

```
{
"TimeZones":[
  {
    "value": "Dateline Standard Time",
    "abbr": "DST",
    "offset": "-12",
    "isdst": false,
    "text": "(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West"
  },

  {
    "value": "Hawaiian Standard Time",
    "abbr": "HST",
    "offset": "-10",
    "isdst": false,
    "text": "(UTC-10:00) Hawaii"
  },
  {
    "value": "Alaskan Standard Time",
    "abbr": "AKDT",
    "offset": "-8",
    "isdst": true,
    "text": "(UTC-09:00) Alaska"
  },
  {
    "value": "Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)",
    "abbr": "PDT",
    "offset": "-7",
    "isdst": true,
    "text": "(UTC-08:00) Baja California"
  },
  {
    "value": "Pacific Standard Time",
    "abbr": "PDT",
    "offset": "-7",
    "isdst": true,
    "text": "(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
  },
```

2) I read this raw data and stored content in two Hashmaps a) **twentyfourhour** b) **twelvehour**

3) **twentyfourhour** Hashmap has time stored in 24 hour format, **twelvehour** Hashmap has time stored in 12 hour format

4) I created two  string array lists to hold these Hashmaps

> stringArrayList.add(twentyfourhour); //adding 24 hour hashmap to
>   arraylist                stringArrayListtwelve.add(twelvehour);
>   //adding 12 hour hashmap to arraylist

5) Based on User choice of hour format I create a new handler and assign to Adapter using ternary operator

```
//Assign ArrayList Strings based on Hour format 0 = 24 hour format, 1 = 12 hour format
listAdapter = (hour_counter == 0) ? new TwocolumnAdapter(object, stringArrayList) : new TwocolumnAdapter(object,stringArrayListtwelve);

// Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter                    
mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
```

## My Question:

Can i update my adapters without create new adapters every time?(As in point 5)

Please advice me with better approach, I am creating new objects every time.

Comment: Well, a listview item has only 2 textviews, right? if so, just change the right textview..

Comment: Create a public function in your adapter, sth like changeTimeFormat() and put the time changing logic inside one adapter

Comment: use SimpleDateFormat or your current method to change format, inside a method, could be in the adapter, or a method in some Util class, in that method, get selected Format type from settings, and format the date

Comment: @ChrisK.: If I invoke that public function to change data, does `notifyDataSetChanged()` function call auto updates the view???

Comment: @Yazan: I am using a Hasmap<String,String>, i should change to Hasmap<string,date> isn't ??

Comment: @Paul: Thanks for your reply, where should i change the content, In adapter?? and how should i push back changes ??

Comment: @Sudarshan yes you can switch to <String,Date> or keep it <String,String> as SimpleDateFormat can parse(String) and Format(Date) so you can do it 2 steps if you stick to <String, String>